# Problem with finding this integral

Tags: warning-messages

l am trying to find this integral by Mathmatica, but there is some problem that Mathmatica does not give any answer, there is method to solve this integration

```
Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0 && ρ ⩾ 1 && u > 0, 
Integrate[E^(- 
(x/(a^2 + b^2)))/((a^2 + b^2)^2 π ρ Sqrt[(-u + x + 
x ρ)/((a^2 + b^2) ρ)] Sqrt[(u - x + x ρ)/(
 a^2 ρ + b^2 ρ)]),{x,u/(1 + ρ),infinity}]]`
```

[image]

Comment: Please post also the codes you have tried.

Comment: i added it now,thanks

Comment: there is no antiderivative. Try numerical integration.

Comment: but i cannot use numerical integration since the limits of the integral is not a numerical value

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

With 12.0.0 I did run

```
Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0 && \[Rho] \[GreaterSlantEqual] 1 && u > 0, Integrate[E^(-(x/(a^2 + b^2)))/((a^2 + b^2)^2 \[Pi] \[Rho] Sqrt[(-u + x + 
  x \[Rho])/((a^2 + b^2) \[Rho])] Sqrt[(u - x + x \[Rho])/(
 a^2 \[Rho] + b^2 \[Rho])]),{x,u/(1 + \[Rho]),infinity}]]
```

and got the result:

```
ConditionalExpression[((a^2 + b^2) (1 - 
       E^(-(infinity/(a^2 + b^2)))) + (a^2 + b^2) infinity + (
    2 (u (-1 + Sqrt[1 + (infinity (-1 + \[Rho]))/u]) + 
       infinity Sqrt[
        1 + (infinity (-1 + \[Rho]))/u] (-1 + \[Rho])) Sqrt[
     u/((a^2 + b^2) \[Rho])])/(3 (-1 + \[Rho])) + infinity \[Rho] + (
    2 infinity Sqrt[(u (infinity - u + infinity \[Rho]))/(
     infinity^2 (1 + \[Rho])^2)])/Sqrt[\[Pi]] + 
    Log[1 + (infinity (-1 + \[Rho]))/u]/(-1 + \[Rho]))/((a^2 + 
      b^2)^2 \[Pi] \[Rho] Sqrt[u/(
    a^2 \[Pi] \[Rho] + b^2 \[Pi] \[Rho])]), (Re[u] < 0 && Im[u] == 0 &&
     Re[infinity] > 0 && Im[infinity] == 0 && 
    1 + Re[\[Rho]] < u/infinity && Im[\[Rho]] == 0 && 
    Re[a^2 + b^2] > 0) || (Re[u] > 0 && Im[u] == 0 && 
    Im[\[Rho]] == 0 && 
    Re[a^2 + b^2] > 
     0 && ((infinity == 
         u && (Re[\[Rho]] >= 
           1 || (Re[1/(a^2 + b^2)] > 0 && Re[\[Rho]] > 0))) || (Im[
          infinity] == 
         0 && ((u < 2 Re[infinity] && 
            u > Re[infinity] && (Re[\[Rho]] >= 
               1 || (Re[1/(a^2 + b^2)] > 0 && 
                u/infinity < 1 + Re[\[Rho]]))) || (u >= 
             2 Re[infinity] && Re[infinity] > 0 && 
            u/infinity < 1 + Re[\[Rho]]) || (u < 
             Re[infinity] && (Re[\[Rho]] >= 
               1 || (Re[1/(a^2 + b^2)] > 0 && 
                u/infinity + Re[\[Rho]] > 1)))))))]
```

Comment: humm is it possible you got an answer because you used `infinity` instead of `Infinity` as the limit?

Answer (score 0):

> but i cannot use numerical integration since the limits of the
>   integral is not a numerical value

It works for me. Using V 12.1. In numerical integration you need to use numerical values for the parameters involved.

```
ClearAll[x];
a = 1; b = 2; ρ = 3; u = 4;
NIntegrate[E^(-(x/(a^2 + b^2)))/((a^2 + b^2)^2 π ρ Sqrt[(-u + x + 
        x ρ)/((a^2 + b^2) ρ)] Sqrt[(u - x + 
        x ρ)/(a^2 ρ + b^2 ρ)]), {x, u/(1 + ρ), 
  Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[x,f];
f[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, ρ_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{x},
   NIntegrate[E^(-(x/(a^2 + b^2)))/((a^2 + b^2)^2 π ρ Sqrt[(-u + x + 
        x ρ)/((a^2 + b^2) ρ)] Sqrt[(u - x + 
        x ρ)/(a^2 ρ + b^2 ρ)]), {x, u/(1 + ρ), Infinity}]
   ];

Plot[f[a, 2, 3, 4], {a, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "integral"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
Plot3D[f[a, b, 3, 4], {a, 0, 5}, {b, 2, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ok, but if  i want the answer in general without specify a value for the constant, it does not work right?

Comment: @DoaaSleem yes, since there is no analytical anti derivative for this, your other choice is to use numerical integration. But you could always make a function that takes in these parameters, this way you could plot the integral for different values of the parameters and see how it changes vs. parameter.

Comment: ok , that is mean there is no closed form for this integral, and by evaluate it in different value i can plot the pdf and the cdf?

Comment: @DoaaSleem yes. no closed form. I've added an example how to plot vs. one parameter.

Comment: ok, i can plot it with respect to more than one parameter or not ?

Comment: @DoaaSleem Yes, you can plot vs. 2 parameters also and get 3D plot. Will add example. You can also add Manipulate, this way you can change the slider and see the effect for different values right away. You know how to do this?

Comment: @ Nasser Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: no, i don't know how to do it